# Elevate UAC prompt for .net application using manifest file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, uac

I have created an sample winforms application where need to elevate UAC prompt once user double clicks or execute.

To elevate same have created manifest file "WindowsFormsApp1.exe.manifest" and placed where "WindowsFormsApp1.exe" is there as per link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Manifest file xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="Any CPU"
     name="WindowsFormsApp1"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

[image: .Exe and manifest file location]
By placing manifest file still getting UAC prompt, ***How to elevate UAC prompt using manifest file?***

Comment: The program already has a manifest, the OS won't look for a file.  Modify that embedded manifest instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034

Answer (score 2):

As per the linked document, the manifest must be embedded within the application. Placing a separate manifest file next to the executable will not have the desired effect.

Add the manifest file to your project, and then use the project properties page to select it under the "icon and manifest" section. Rebuild your project, and the application should prompt for elevation when you launch it.

Comment: Thanks Richard, Using Mt.exe we can embed manifest to application.exe here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/mt-exe